# symfony v3.3.6 unexpected service behaviour

Tags: php, dependency-injection, autowired, symfony-3.3

Im working on a Symfony3 project and playing around with the "new" dependency injection mechanism.
can some please explain the following behavior to me please:

this is my setup:

---

### services.yml

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  MyBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller/'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

  MyBundle\A: 
    public:false
```

### Controller Scenario A

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use ...

class RootController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="root")
     */
    public function indexAction(A $a) <- INJECTION HERE
    {
        $b = $this->get(A::class); // NO EXCEPTION THROWN HERE

        return new Response(); 
    }
}
```

### Controller Scenario B

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use ...

class RootController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="root")
     */
    public function indexAction() // <- NO INJECTION
    {
        $b = $this->get(A::class); // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE

        return new Response(); 
    }
}
```

Im trying to fetch service `A` inside the `indexAction` from the container. As I marked it private in my `services.yml` I'm expecting an Exception when trying to grab it (like in `Scenario B`). But in `Scenario A` I'm not getting an Exception because the service `A` has already been injected (auto wired) into the Controller.

(here the (expected) Exception of Scenario B: `You have requested a non-existent service "MyBundle\A".`)

Can some explain this behaviour please.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bit of explaining in the comments I understand your question as:

**How does a private service becomes public by request in the controller action?**

With action injection these services collected are re-registred with `ServiceLocator` class, which make it accessible with `->get()`.

See [`RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/9c6e67278069e86350d196e386dba1183ed6ea4f#diff-58d1479352b43b312746ea6ceb4ada96R135) here.

[image]

I agree it's a bit unclear behavior. Not all paths can be covered I guess.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: It does, since both scenarios are invalid. Could you explain a bit more? Have you tried it?

Comment: No, Scenario A is perfectly fine. You are talking about method injection, while im talking about symfonys DI.

Comment: It works, that's true, but is not valid. You require the service in method argument, then again from DI container. No need to, you already have it :) 

Both your scenarios are method injection in Symfony DI.

Comment: Yes, I just refer to its invalid code that will cause you more WTF like this in the future, like this: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default

It's common that framework do not expect every uses case people use it and throw nice informative exception. That's not their job. They're to simply most common cases, that would be too expensive to cover by yourself.

Comment: But to your answer: I guess that with action injection these services collected are re-registred with "ServiceLocator" class, which make it accessiable with ->get(): see here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/9c6e67278069e86350d196e386dba1183ed6ea4f#diff-58d1479352b43b312746ea6ceb4ada96R135

Comment: If this WTF still remains in Symfony 3.4, you can report it as an issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues I think Symfony team doesn't might wanna fix this

Comment: thx the reregistering does explain scenario A. it produces a very strange behaviour regarding visibility/accessibility of services.

Comment: Thx for the effort

Comment: Glad to help! Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

Invalid behavior of private services is described here:
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-improved-private-services

> Requesting a private service with the Container::get() method is deprecated in Symfony 3.2 and no longer returns the service in 4.0.

Does it log any 'deprecated' in developers log?